# Add custom fields to Django rest_framework APIException

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

I am subclassing Django's rest framework APIException class to create custom API exceptions. For example, one of my exceptions look like this:

```
class Unauthorized(APIException):
    status_code = 401
    default_detail = 'You have to login first.'
    default_code = 'ERR_UNAUTHORIZED'
```

And I've written a custom exception handler to modify key names.
This is the part in my exception handler that deals with these kinds of exceptions:

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
     response.data['code'] = response.data['detail'].code
     response.data['message'] = response.data['detail']
     print(response.data)
     del response.data['detail']
     return response
```

As a result, the output for my exceptions looks like this :

```
{
    "code": "ERR_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "message": "You have to login first."
}
```

What I need to do is that I want to add a new field to my exceptions so that my exception output becomes like the below example:

```
{
    "code": "ERR_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "message": "You have to login first.",
    "extra" : "{ "description" : "extra info" }"
}
```

And in my views, I want to throw this exception like this :

```
raise Unauthorized(extra={ "description" : "extra info" })
```

I'm quite new to Django rest_framework and I've searched about this and also tried to add the `"another field"` to my custom exception class fields but that couldn't solve my problem. Are there any ways to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer myself (which is not really clean). We can throw exceptions in our serializers like below:

```
 raise serializers.ValidationError({"info" : "test info"})
```

And in the custom exception handler we can handle this scenario like this:

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):

    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError): 
        resp_copy = response.data
        del response.data
        response.data = {}
        if(response.status_code == 400):
            response.data['code'] = 'ERR_UNAUTHORIZED'
            response.data['message'] = 'some errors occurred'
            response.data['extra'] = {}
            for key in resp_copy:
                response.data['extra'][key] = resp_copy[key]
```

The output will be in the form below:

```
{
    "code": "ERR_UNAUTHORIZED",
    "message": "some errors occurred",
    "extra": {
        "info": [
            "test info"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
     response.data['code'] = response.data['detail'].code
     response.data['message'] = response.data['detail']

     response.data['another_field'] = { "description" : "extra info" }

     print(response.data)
     del response.data['detail']
     return response
```

Hope this helps you....

Additional Answer

```
class Unauthorized(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errors):

        # Call the base class constructor with the parameters it needs
        super(ValidationError, self).__init__(message)

        # Now for your custom code...
        self.errors = errors
```

Raise the exception where you want

```
raise Unauthorized("Your message")
```

And catch the exception

```
try:
    ...
except Unauthorized as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But what if I need to send another field as an argument when I'm raising the exception? raise Unauthorized(another_field = data)